# Phantom: Detected both log4j-over-slf4j.jar AND bound slf4j-log4j12.jar on the class path,

Tags: scala, apache-spark, log4j, slf4j, phantom-dsl

I have just plugged my spark application into Cassandra. I am using the Phantom Cassandra driver.

Now I get the following error during unit testing

> Detected both log4j-over-slf4j.jar AND bound slf4j-log4j12.jar on the
>   class path

The Exception is thrown during SparkCintext Initialization,
This is caused because I now have Phantom dependencies in my pom.xml. (Seems crazy that Phantom would have a direct conflict with Spark, but there it is)

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.outworkers</groupId>
        <artifactId>phantom-dsl_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.24.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I can add an exclusion to Phantom to prevent `log4j-over-slf4j.jar`.

QUESTION:
Is it safe to exclude `log4j-over-slf4j.jar` from Phantom or will it cause problems further down the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly safe to exclude `log4j-over-slf4j.jar` from Phantom. It will not cause any problem other than logging library management. Which can be handled by `slf4j-log4j12.jar`.